# Accessing a Site Developed with Magento Community Edition using Mobile Clients

Tags: magento-community, design, mobile, shopping

I intend to develop an e-commerce solution using Magento Community Edition (free version). The solution needs to cater mobile clients (e.g. mobile phone web browsers) as well (i.e. Android phone users will access the site for shopping). In this case, is it be possible to use Magento Community Edition ? Can we develop a customized theme with responsive design features to cater mobile clients ?

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The default theme of Magento is not responsive.

However there is a theme called "iphone" in stock that can be configured to be used with mobiles devices detected form the user agent string. This is not a responsive theme but just a very simplified layout for mobile devices. This can suit very basic needs but for more advanced mobile support you will need a custom responsive theme. Additionally mobile agent detection is always very approximate.

There are lost of custom responsive themes for Magento out there (free and commercials). Just Google for "magento responsive theme" and you will get lots of promising results.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the default theme is not responsive you can develop your own responsive template without problem. Check on themeforest in magento section you will find ton of responsive theme for Magento.

A few suggestions:

http://themeforest.net/item/buyshop-premium-responsive-retina-magento-theme/4287671
http://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798

Comment: Do you have any experience with a specific theme?

Comment: I'am currently working with one of them. http://themeforest.net/item/buyshop-premium-responsive-retina-magento-theme/4287671